# How to install MS SQL Server on Windows Server 2012 with virtual environment?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, installation

I am working in SharePoint content publishing and branding. Now I am interested to learn more about central administration site , search and so on.
I don't have full access in the office. So I decide to set-up share point environment in my laptop.

I installed VMware workstation 11 and have installed windows server 2012, I have also configure active directory for development environment now can anyone please suggest me what next??

I mean how to install MS SQL server and SharePoint server in VM...to run SharePoint 2013..I am sorry if I am not clear.

Comment: Have you tried [google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=setup+sharepoint+2013+development+environment)?

Comment: yes, I did..could not find it ..I am just missing the trick after configuration of AD..how to install SQL within VM in windows server..Do I need to add new VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is learning VM so that it is ok having AD on same server where you have SharePoint.

after installation and Configuration of VM and OS. You need to do following steps

- Configure Server
- Install SQL Server 2012
- Install SharePoint 2013

How to install it, please check blog for complete details/steps.http://www.jeanpaulva.com/index.php/2014/01/23/installing-sharepoint-2013-on-virtual-machine/

Comment: Hi Waqas..thanks for the post just wanted to ask, for the installation of SQL server and SharePoint server..I need to copy the installation file from shared folder or i can link through iso image file too.. and can I install everything on one virtual machine right? as I said this is for personal learning?

Comment: for personal yes you can install it on single VM...You can isntall it via mounting the ISO  as well as you can copy the files....if you have plenty space on drive then can copy.

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot ..I don't know ..mounting ISO file was not working ..today I will try shared folder way ..thanks again :) just to confirm I have I5 with 12 gb ram ..Is it sufficient for me?

Comment: for personal use, it is enogh...if you face any performance issue then after SharePoint configuration stop all the un necessary services...

Comment: i am not sure what you asking.

Comment: I was asking when I created my virtual environment. I allotted 8gb ram out of 12..how much I should give while creating virtual enviornment for sharepoint 2013..I am sorry I was not clear..

Comment: i think it is enough but you will see the slow perfomance.